# Need help with this SEA Math Competition question! Geometry

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving

**Two of the altitudes of a scalene triangle with integer-length sides are 6 and 14 units.
Given that the third altitude is also an integer, what is the maximum it can be?**

*This was a multiple choice question, and the options were;*
A.7

B.9

C.11

D.12

E.13

The strategy I used was;
Derive an equation or an inequality to represent the third altitude and maximise the variables inside the equation, I tried doing this by naming all lengths, including the ones that were split up by the altitude. Then creating inequalities based of off the triangle inequality. I tried reducing them down into a few inequalities so that I could maximise the length of the other altitude, but it didn't work :(. I realised there were too many variables to deal with and gave up.

Comment: Good, you already did so much work, you should write it down or us and then we can tell you how to improve the approach. Waiting for that. Shouldn’t take you long. Good luck.

Comment: In addition to the triangle inequalities, use the fact that the base times altitude is twice the area.

Comment: Voting to close as lacking context because it seems like the “context” provided is a bluff. Will retract vote if the vaunted work appears finally.

Answer (score 0):

Inequalities, yes. But which ones?

We must know two basic facts about triangles to solve this problem:

$\color{blue}{FIRST.-}$ THE PRODUCT OF THE LENGTHS OF A SIDE AND THE ALTITUDE TO THAT SIDE EQUALS TWICE THE AREA.

So if denote twice the area by K and let a, b, and c be the sides corresponding to the altitudes of length 4, 12, and h, we get the formulas,

$a = K/4$, $b = K/12$, $c = K/h$

$\color{blue}{SECOND.-}$ A TRIANGLE EXISTS WITH SIDE LENGTHS a, b, AND c IF AND ONLY IF THEY SATISFY THE THREE TRIANGLE INEQUALITIES:

$a < b + c$, $b < c + a$, and $c < a + b$.

At this point, with some algebra knowledge, it is possible to deduce the largest possible value of h immediately.

If you are not confident with algebra, you can test the integer values of h starting at h = 1 (and skipping h = 4 and h = 12 to avoid isosceles triangles) to discover the largest value of h for which a, b, and c satisfy the triangle inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

Revision:
The triangle of interest is $ABC$ with given elevations of $14$ and $6$. My solution is based on conjecture but I do use two extreme examples to determine the nearest integer from the answer options.

Because $BD = 6$ is less than half the elevation $14$, $DC$ will always be shorter than $AD$. As angle $\alpha$ approaches $90$ degrees and angle $\theta$ becomes smaller, the ratio of $DC$ to $AD$ reaches a maximum.

For an extreme case where $\theta = 0.1$ then $\alpha = 89.76667$. $AC = 6016.04$ and $AD = 3437.74$ The elevation $EC \approx 6\cdot \frac{6016.04}{3437.74} \approx 10.5$ max. An extreme in the other direction where $\theta = 25$ then $\alpha = 9.561$ with a resulting elevation $EC \approx 7.18$ Between these extremes answer $B = 9$ is therefore the max integer possible.

[image]